# Can i count how many atributtes of one type in the node using xpath expressions?

Tags: xml, xpath

Imagine i have this:

```
<code idref="i_01 i_02 i_03 i_04"/>
```

can i count using an xpath expression?

```
count(//code/@idref)
```

i tried to use this expression but only shows "1"

Comment: Yes. What have you tried?

Comment: @Jim Garrison  count(//code/@idref)

Comment: Update your question using the [edit] capability to show us the xpath expression in context.

Comment: @Jim Garrison done

Comment: @Matos, perhaps, you want to count the **values** within *idref* attribute? And you are expecting it to be 4 ?

Comment: @Jim Garrison, i have 4 idref in that node so i wanted an expression that result in "4", but maybe i need to have 4 code for each idref right?

Comment: @Jim Garrison yeah!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//code/count(tokenize(@idref))
```

It yields the count of whitespace separated tokens in the `@idref` attribute of each `code` element.

I'm assuming here that your `@idref` attribute is actually referring to an [IDREFS](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/CR-xmlschema-2-20001024/#IDREFS) type as of XML Schema. In that case, the individual IDREF references will be whitespace separated, and tokenize does exactly what you need.

If you instead want to sum up the token counts over *all* `code` elements, use

```
count(//code/tokenize(@idref))
```

Answer (score 0):

In xpath 1.0, there is no way to do that.

`count()` is an node-set function, it will return the number of element in the node-set, in you case, `@idref` is the element in the node-set. it's can not be divided, so there is no way to do that

Answer (score 0):

well if you know the format of the values you're gonna count (i_01) and there's less than a hundred instances all the time, then:

`round(string-length(string(//code/@idref)) div 5)`